# Can't add any corodova plugin to my app

Tags: cordova, ionic-native

I am facing a problem.
I am working on ionic 2 app mobile.
I am trying to add cordova plugin to my mobile app. 
At the console it show me this error:

```
[18:13:06]  typescript: ...s/users/mypath/node_modules/@ionic-native/in-app-browser/index.d.ts, line: 143
                Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

         L143:  export declare class InAppBrowser extends IonicNativePlugin {
```

I tried to install another plugin and it's the same error.

When I create a new project and try to install same plugins, it works. 
I am not allowed to re-create a new project and copy my work.
How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall the ionic native 
npm install @ionic-native/core --save